# Two bytes into one

Tags: c++, casting, bit-manipulation

First off, I apologize if this is a duplicate; but my Google-fu seems to be failing me today.

I'm in the middle of writing an image format module for Photoshop, and one of the save options for this format, includes a 4-bit alpha channel. Of course, the data I have to convert is 8-bit/1 byte alpha - so I need to essentially take every two bytes of alpha, and merge it into one.

my attempt (below), I believe has a lot of room for improvement:

```
for(int x=0,w=0;x < alphaData.size();x+=2,w++)
{
     short ashort=(alphaData[x] << 8)+alphaData[x+1];
     alphaFinal[w]=(unsigned char)ashort;
}
```

alphaData and alphaFinal are vectors that contains the 8-bit alpha data and the 4-bit alpha data, respectively. I realize that reducing two bytes into the value of one, is bound to result in loss of "resolution", but I can't help but think there's a better way of doing this.

For extra information, here's the loop that does the reverse (converts 4-bit alpha from the format to 8-bit for Photoshop)

alphaData serves the same purpose as above, and imgData is an unsigned char vector that holds the raw image data. (alpha data is tacked on after the actual rgb data for the image in this particular variant of the format)

```
for(int b=alphaOffset,x2=0;b < (alphaOffset+dataLength); b++,x2+=2)
{
    unsigned char lo = (imgData[b] & 15);
    unsigned char hi = ((imgData[b] >> 4) & 15);
    alphaData[x2]=lo*17;
    alphaData[x2+1]=hi*17;
 }
```

Comment: +1 just for the Google-Fu word-play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's

```
alphaData[x2]=lo*17;
alphaData[x2+1]=hi*17;
```

and not

```
alphaData[x2]=lo*16;
alphaData[x2+1]=hi*16;
```

In any case, to generate the values that work with the decoding function you have posted, you just have to reverse the operations.  So multiplying by 17 becomes dividing by 17 and the shifts and masks get reordered to look like this:

```
for(int x=0,w=0;x < alphaData.size();x+=2,w++)
{
    unsigned char alpha1 = alphaData[x] / 17;
    unsigned char alpha2 = alphaData[x+1] / 17;
    Assert(alpha1 < 16 && alpha2 < 16);
    alphaFinal[w]=(alpha2 << 4) | alpha1;
}
```

Comment: At first I thought it would be *16, except, with that, the first image I tested ended up being semi-transparent. Looking back, I noticed that 15 (the highest value of a nibble) * 16 = 240, instead of 255. 

At any rate, I seem to have a habit of overlooking the obvious. Thanks, it worked great!

Comment: I think you should do the division with rounding, i.e. `(alphaData[x] + 8) / 17`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  short ashort=(alphaData[x] << 8)+alphaData[x+1];
  alphaFinal[w]=(unsigned char)ashort;
```

You're actually losing alphaData[x] in alphaFinal. You shift alphaData[x] by 8 bits to the left and then assign 8 low bits.

Also your for loop is unsafe, if for some reason alphaData.size() is odd, you'll run out of range.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's bad practice - but it's kinda my odd way of doing a "rough draft". But thanks for the explanation about the first part - it certainly helps explain the result I got.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do, I think, is to truncate an 8-bit value into a 4-bit one; not to combine two 8-bit vales. In other words, you want to drop the four least significant bits of each alpha value, not to combine two different alpha values.
So, basically, you want to right-shift by 4.

```
output = (input >> 4); /* truncate four bits */
```

in case you're not familiar with binary shifts, take this random 8-bit number:

```
10110110
>> 1
= 01011011
>> 1
= 00101101
>> 1
= 00010110
>> 1
= 00001011
```

so,

```
10110110
>> 4
= 00001011
```

and to reverse, left-shift instead...

```
input = (output << 4); /* expand four bits */
```

which, using the result from that same random 8-bit number as before, would be

```
00001011
>> 4
= 10110000
```

obviously, as you noted, 4 bits of precision is lost. But you'd be surprised how little it's noticed in a fully-composited work.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
for(int x=0,w=0;x < alphaData.size();x+=2,w++)
{
     short ashort=(alphaData[x] << 8)+alphaData[x+1];
     alphaFinal[w]=(unsigned char)ashort;
}
```

Is broken. Given

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int main() {
    uchar x0 = 1; // for alphaData[x]
    uchar x1 = 2; // for alphaData[x+1]

    short ashort    = (x0 << 8) + x1; // The value 0x0102
    uchar afinal  = (uchar)ashort; // truncates to 0x02.

    cout << std::hex
         << "x0 = 0x" << x0 << " << 8 = 0x" << (x0 << 8) << endl
         << "x1 = 0x" << x1 << endl
         << "ashort = 0x" << ashort << endl
         << "afinal = 0x" << (unsigned int)afinal << endl
    ;
}
```

If you are saying that your source stream contains sequences of 4-bit pairs stored in 8-bit storage values, which you need to re-store as a single 8-bit value, then what you want is:

```
for(int x=0,w=0;x < alphaData.size();x+=2,w++)
{
    unsigned char aleft = alphaData[x] & 0x0f; // 4 bits.
    unsigned char aright = alphaData[x + 1] & 0x0f;  // 4 bits.
    alphaFinal[w] = (aleft << 4) | (aright);
}
```

"<<4" is equivalent to "*16", as ">>4" is equivalent to "/16".